# Trying to get GPO command for EMV Card failed

Tags: java, apdu, emv

I have been working on a Pos terminal app for Pax A930 device. I was able to AID, card type and etc but when i tried the GPO command, it throws 6985 error. I am not sure issues is from my end or whether the SDK got any issue.

Request 1 :

```
00A404000E315041592E5359532E444446303100
```

Response :

```
6F1E840E315041592E5359532E4444463031A50C8801015F2D02656E9F1101019000
```

> ---

Request 2 :

```
00B2010C00
```

Response:

```
7021611F4F07A00000000310105004564953419F120A564953412044454249548701019000
```

> ---

Request 3:

```
00A4040005A0000000031010
```

Response

```
6F3D8408A000000003000000A5319F6E9000
```

Everything works perfectly upto here but when i try to execute the GPO

```
80A800000283000000
```

I get 6985

As per my knowledge i didnt get PDOL response from the 3rd call, so i am using the commonly used command for the GPO.

can someone guide me on this?

Comment: are you sure that the SELECT command has correct Len specifier? 00A4040005A0000000031010 - here you define 00 A4 04 00 - SELECT command, 05 - the length of the payload, but the payload consist of 7 bytes (A0 00 00 00 03 10 10)

Comment: According to `https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/complete-list-of-application-identifiers-aid` the dedicated file name provided by the card (" A000000003000000") is NOT pointing to a regular payment card/application but to a **Global Payment* one (see: *(VISA) Card Manager: Used by most GP2.1.1 cards / Oberthur OP201 cards. Visa Proprietary Card Manager AID for OpenPlatform cards (visa.openplatform).*). Probably you need additional documents provided from Visa to process the card.

Comment: @user478681 when i tried with length 07, i receive only SW1 and SW2 as 9000. no response data but when i mention the 05, i receive the above response. Do oyu think this might be a manufactorer error?

Comment: @MichaelFehr i will try to find addtitional doc. Sometime i feel like device got manufacturer error. I don't receive values properly for the commands sometime.

Comment: @ZumryMohamed, sorry, have no idea. Even the response to request 3 looks not correct to me (at least it is not a TLV coded data). Either you have manufactorer error or some issue with logging. Try to read the card using some external tool

Comment: Honestly, it seems that you are not using a certified kernel. The commands you are showing would not have been sent by it. You have not select the application properly, but a card manager instead. I don't know what you are doing, but it is not a payment application as this way you won't get through L3 certifications without using certified L2 kernels.